# How does one model a squilion to squilion relationship in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, one-to-many, data-modeling

How does one model a squilion to squilion relationship in mongodb?

Something like users and post-likes.... A user can like over a squilion posts and a post can have over a squilion users that like it.

In one to squilion relationship, the identifier is placed in the child data, either by referencing or embedding. How does this translate over to squilion to squilion?

Comment: One of the aspects that affect the design is the most accessed data / queried of the  - users and posts. What are your important queries. Referencing and embedding are  influenced by these factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dedicated model and collection for the likes. Each like references the post and the user.